# DevOps change name of build depending on what branch is being built

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

With Azure DevOps, is there a was to set the name of the build and artifact based on the repository that its being build?

E.g. if we build the dev branch we want the name to be as shown at the bottom of the example

```
trigger:
- develop
- release/*
- hotfix/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  versionNumber: 1.10.0
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'

name: $(versionNumber)-wip-$(Rev:r)

... etc
```

In the case of a release branch we want the name to be

```
name: $(versionNumber)-release-$(Rev:r)
```

and the case of hotfix we want the name to be

```
name: $(versionNumber)-hotfix-$(Rev:r)
```

Other than creating multiple azure-pipelines.yml files which then means we have almost duplicate files.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for that jessehouwing.

The approach I managed to get working is shown below. The **Build.SourceBranch** was useful to know

```
variables:
  ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/develop') }}:
    branchName: 'wip'
  ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/release') }}:
    branchName: 'release'
  ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/hotfix') }}:
    branchName: 'hotfix'
        
    name: $(versionNumber)-$(branchName)-$(Rev:r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
name: $(versionnumber)-$(Build.SourceBranchName)-$(Rev:r)
```

That should inject [the branch name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) (the last part of the name after the `/`):

> ### `Build.SourceBranchName`
>
> The name of the branch in the triggering repo the build was queued for.
> Git repo branch or pull request: The last path segment in the ref. For example, in `refs/heads/master` this value is `master`. In `refs/heads/feature/tools` this value is `tools`.

There is a slightly different variable you can use too, but it contains all the slashes and `/refs/heads`, in which case you may want to use a task to set the name while the build is running.

> ### `Build.SourceBranch`
>
> The branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for. Some examples:
>
> - Git repo branch: `refs/heads/master`
> - Git repo pull request: `refs/pull/1/merge`

My [Transform Variable task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks) may help with that:

```
- task: VariableTransformTask@1
  inputs:
    value: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    variableName: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    IsSecret: false
    transformAction: 'none'
    searchReplace: true
    searchReplaceMethod: 'basic'
    searchValue: '/'
    replacementValue: '-'
```

Or run a custom script that [logs a special string to update the variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number):

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $buildnumber = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
      $branchname = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH -replace "/", "-"
      
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildnumber-$branchname"
```

Comment: I gave that as a 2ndkipdion, didn't I? @orenrevenge. There are 6000+ azure DevOps orgs using that extension for 7 years now. It's pretty battle hardened...